# Concealing a character in Vim without affecting how it's highlighted

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I would like to show ‘␣’ instead of non-breaking spaces since they are invisible by default, and added the following lines to my `vimrc`:

```
syntax match nonbreaking "\%xa0" conceal cchar=␣
set conceallevel=1
highlight nonbreaking ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE
```

While this works, it also adds a background colour to all occurrences of non-breaking spaces – even with the `{cterm,gui}bg=NONE` line:

[image]

Is there a way to “hide” U+00ad behind ‘␣’ without affecting how it's highlighted at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well, it's not a direct answer to your question about background of concealed characters, though here is a solution to your problem:

to show non-breakable spaces as `␣` you should better use the `listchars` setting:

```
:set listchars=nbsp:␣
```

and here's my complete `listchars` setting, in case you're interested:

```
:set listchars=eol:¶,trail:~,extends:⫸,precedes:⫷,tab:▸ ,nbsp:␣
```

and this will not affect the colours.

More about it [`:he listchars`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27listchars%27)

HTH

Comment: Nice! I didn't know there was a `nbsp` in listchars. I'll consider enabling `list` for all files. (Right now I only enable it for code.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd also recommend against using the *conceal* feature for this, as it can interfere with the existing syntax highlighting; the use of `'listchars'` as suggested by @zmo is preferable (but `:set list` has side effects, e.g. with wrapping, too).

For completeness, you can influence the visual appearance of the concealed characters via the `Conceal` highlight group.

```
:hi clear Conceal
```

clears the existing highlighting.